# Which functions in OpenSSL send to server and receive from server during SSL Handshake?

Tags: security, ssl, openssl

I have to measure the time difference between sending the Client Key Exchange message and Receiving the response from server during SSL Handshake. Where should I put my code to capture the time difference. I am not sure exactly which function is sending the message and receiving the response during handshake.

Comment: Unless I am much mistaken, OpenSSL doesn't expose the individual messages. It just tells you when it needs a read or a write, and you obey.

Comment: @EJP Did not understand. Could you please elaborate.